# Mongoose aggregate Get count and append new value to the query result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Given that I have this two COLLECTIONS:**.

1st.col

```
users:
{
  _id :34,
 name :"mama mia"   
}
```

2nd.col

```
posts:
{
  _id :67
 body :" hello mongoose"
 likes:[ 0: ObjectId("34") ]

}
```

I wanna get every posts with likes count.
And let suppose if I have a auth user id ready and a want to map through the likes and if the `user._id`(auth id) is found in the post likes  i wanna append a new attribute to the collection result not in the db , i just want  to modifies the result i'm gonna get.

To make more since of my question , this is the result expected :

```
[
 {
      _id  : 67
     body  : " hello mongoose"
     likesCount : 1
     liked :true
     likes :{
       "34":{
            name :"mama mia" 
        }
     }
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$lookup` to join users collection
- `$map` to iterate loop of `likes` array and return key-value format result
- `$arrayToObject` to convert key-value array of object to object
- `$size` to get total elements in `likes` array
- `$in` to check current auth user id in `likes` array or not

```
let auth_user_id = ObjectId("34");
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "likes",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "likes"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      likes: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$likes",
            in: {
              k: { $toString: "$$this._id" },
              v: "$$this.name"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      likesCount: { $size: "$likes" },
      liked: { $in: [auth_user_id, "$likes"] },
      body: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dOesCvQ29gc)

Comment: hi buddy, i dont feel any purpose to join with user collection, right!!

Comment: yes right he has mentioned *I have a auth user id ready*.

Comment: @varman wt do you mean then , how am I gonna know if the user liked the post or not ?

Comment: in your expected result, you didn't show anything about the user information. That's why we discussed

Comment: hi buddy, @varman you're right , I just modifies the question. I wanna return the likes with user info in them

Comment: First thank you a lot, but I just updated the question again  sorry

Comment: @DimerBwimba its totally different  than your previous question, you can ask new question instead of updating current question. see how to [ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: okay, I apologize . thank you for the answer tho. This is Gonna help me a lot . @turivishal

Comment: @turivishal I have a small problem here , even if the user liked the post it keep on returning false

Comment: make sure you have converted your input `auth_user_id` in objectid type, using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(auth_user_id)`

Comment: thank you this fixed my issue, God bless.

Comment: @turivishal I'm near exhaustion brother can you help me with my new question brother.

Comment: @turivishal there's a tiny tiny issue with this answer | The likes count shouldn't be based on the number of  joins result we find  between the user and the likes  on a particular post |  likesCount should be a global count of the post likes.

Comment: @turivishal bruh can you plz look at my last question, i'm kindda lost for real

Comment: i am not getting you, please explain in more details in new question.